# Работа над массивами

Tags: массивы, c, строки

Ввести текст с клавиатуры, число строк которого строго 12, а также массив разделителей. В строках, в которых встречается указанное слово, заменить это слово на другое, также введённое пользователем. Остальные строки удалить. Вывести полученный текст на экран и в файл.
Честно говоря я не понимаю, что такое массив разделителей и до меня даже не доходит как это можно всё написать. Поэтому хотелось бы попросить вашей помощи. Только язык Си

Comment: А это точно одно задание? Как-то пропали разделители и появилось введенное слово.

Что до строк: строки в си как отдельного типа не существует, строка - это массив символов (char). Строку от случайного массива отличает то, что кончается она т.н. null character '\0' (на самом деле, его там может и не быть, но пока это можно не учитывать), и это позволяет не таскать везде вместе со строкой ее длину. Работать со строкой можно как с массивом (потому что она и есть массив), также за счет равенства '\0' == 0 можно делать такой хак:

Comment: while(s[i]) { // оборвется, как только достигнет '\0'
        char c = s[i];
        i++;
    }

Основные строковые функции можно подключить с помощью заголовочного файла `string.h`, там есть, к примеру, функция `strstr()`, которая позволит найти подстроку в строке, и `strlen()`, которая вернет длину строки через нахождение позиции `null character`.

Comment: а можно попросить вас в программе показать это? так будет более понятно

Comment: @himiko, что именно?

Comment: именно замену слов

Comment: [тут](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/replace-a-substring-with-another-string-in-c-170076/) и [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779875/what-is-the-function-to-replace-string-in-c) есть примеры, я написал половину реализации и понял, что двигаюсь куда-то не туда. Проще всего взять заведомо достаточный буфер, затем писать туда сначала из строки, после нахождения вхождения - из строки-замены, потом снова переключатся на обычную строку, и так до конца. Это не очень тривиальная задача с точки зрения возможных ям (разве что если количество символов одинаковое).

Comment: Видимо предполагается, что стока состоит из слов и разделителей.

Для ее разбивки на слова в libc есть пара подходящих функций -- strspn, strcspn (см. соответствующий man).

В GNU для чтения строк произвольной длины есть удобная функция -- getline (сразу получаете строку в динамической памяти (память выделяется malloc)). Но подойдет и пара fgets (в буфер достаточной длины) + strdup.

Замену слов лучше делать путем переписывания строки из одного буфера в другой. В цикле вызовами strspn/strcspn/strncmp фиксируете заданное слово и переписываете байты до него, потом слово замены ... и т.д.

Comment: Подумал тут немного и понял, что для замены наверное все-таки проще использовать для поиска stsstr  и простую проверку символов до и после найденной подстроки на принадлежность разделителям (через strchr). Проверка нужна, чтобы убедиться, что найденная подстрока это именно слово, а не часть какого-то другого слова.

@himiko, я тут набросал кусочек кода для замены. Если у Вас ничего не будет получаться, то выложу.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hvdR9fVe есть вот такой набросок. Компилятор кстати на gets ругается, не знаете, что не так?

Comment: @avp хотелось бы, чтобы показали)

Comment: gets() это "устаревшая" функция. Она небезопасна (в смысле не проверяет переполнение буфера). Поэтому и ругань.

Используйте fgets().

А у меня кодик только насчет замены, сейчас положу в ответ (сюда не влезет, а может и еще кому-нибудь будет полезным). Потом его можно дополнить в том же стиле вводом исходных данных.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct ds {
 char *data;
 int len;
};

void
append (struct ds *s, const char *src, int l1, const char *w, int l2)
{
 int len = s->len + l1 + l2 + 1;
 if (!(s->data = (char *)realloc(s->data, len))) {
   perror("append str");
   exit(-1);
 }
 memcpy(s->data + s->len, src, l1);
 memcpy(s->data + s->len + l1, w, l2);
 s->data[s->len += (l1 + l2)] = 0;
}

char *
replstrw (const char *src, const char *w, const char *r, const char *sep)
{
 struct ds s;
 s.data = 0;
 s.len = 0;
 const char *p, *tt = src, *t = src;
 int wl = strlen(w), rl = strlen(r);

 while (p = strstr(tt, w)) {
   if ((p == src || strchr(sep, p[-1])) && strchr(sep, p[wl])) {
     append(&s, t, p - t, r, rl);
     t = p + wl;
   }
   tt = p + wl;
 }
 if (s.data)
   append(&s, t, strlen(t), "", 0);
 return s.data;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
 char *res = replstrw("abc  12345 qabc abc 567",
      "abc", av[1] ? av[1] : "zxcv", " \n\t,.");

 if (res)
   puts(res);

 return 0;
}
```

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте (уже завтра).

Comment: struct, memcpy, кровь, кишки, replstrw...

А для чего придумали strtok?